# Uploading images via FCKeditor in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, wysiwyg, fckeditor

i'm using WYSIWYG module to implement FCKeditor in drupal. If i want to add an image(upload from the user's system and not an url) in the content, how'd i do?
i've Image, ImageCache modules installed.
or do i need another module for this to be done?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Image/File browser

The integrated file management needs a bit of manual configuration, more information about this is in the included readme.txt file.

At the moment there are several options for using images in FCKeditor.

1. The built in filemanager, which needs some manual configuration.
2. The IMCE module which needs almost no configuration.
3. The Image Browser module
4. The Web File Manager module (available in FCKeditor dev release only at this moment)
5. The Image Assist module
6. The upload module - which allows file and image attachments to nodes. By copying the URL of the attachment you can use it in the FCKeditor dialog.
   "

--Taken from the [FCKEditor module page](http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor)

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to be able to insert images, you need to allow them to upload the image to the server. Then they can insert the image like normal.

I believe there is a module that gives users something a bit like a home folder where they can store images. It should also integrate with WYSIWYG so they would be able to select the image am insert it without knowing about urls etc. It's been quite a while since I saw it and never used it, so you need to do some investigating. But I think it would just what you are looking for.

- take a look at [Image assist module](http://drupal.org/project/img_assist)
- and there is also [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce)

It might have been a demo of one of those two I remember having seen. In any regard you should be able to get what you want with one of them.